# Make a phrase clickable in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextview

I want to know how to make e text clickable and play a sound when a specific text is click.

[image]

I need to detect which phrase has been clicked, play a sound when that phrase is clicked and change the color of that specific phrase.

This is the function when I create the story and assign it to UITextView

```
func showStory(){
    var ph:String?

    var s:String = ""

    var index = 0
    for phrase in phrasesArray {
        ph = phrase
        let data = ph!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        do{
            let txt = try NSAttributedString(data: data!,
                                             options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                       .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                             documentAttributes: nil)

            s = txt.string

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: s, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14) , NSAttributedStringKey.link: audioArray[index]])

            attributedText.append(attributedString)

            index += 1
        }catch{}

        fullStory.attributedText = attributedText

    }
}
```

And this is when I handle if user taps the UITextView

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith audio: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool{

    //This is not working
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: characterRange)

    let soundFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: audio.absoluteString, withExtension: "mp3")

    do{
        try sound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFile!)
        sound.prepareToPlay()

    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

    sound.play()


    return false
}
```

Comment: It looks like your text view delegate signature is wrong. Are you calling this method after you receive the delegate method textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)?

Comment: The delegate method `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)` isn't wrong, but it's deprecated. Your problem lies elsewhere. Can you give some examples of what `phraseArray` contains? Is is plain text or HTML?

Comment: phraseArray contains all phrases of the story as HTML. Is the anything else I can use instead of textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)

Answer (score 0):

First that textView delegate method signature is wrong. Assuming phrases array are an array literal you don't need to covert to Data to assign AttributedStrings. 
I wrote a sample project illustrating how this could be accomplished. The only way you can tap over textview content is assigning an attribute of .link type.
In the example the key is assigning different url to link attribute, if not, CoreText treat the whole textview content as a single link.

[Here´s](https://github.com/bolekhub/textviewTapText) the example project. Take a deep look and let me know if it helps.